# Modeling a nested table into an array

Tags: r, statistics, nested-table

My question is mainly about theoretical considerations and not linked to any specific language. I try to solve this issue in either Python or **R**, but the underlying question is the same.

I have a nested table of known and changing dimensions. "Nested" here is not meant in a database system way, but like this:

[image: Descriptive statistics as a nested table]

What is the best way to model this kind of data in an array? What I currently do is to just iterate from top-left to bottom-right through the table, but this is not really helpful since there is no standard way of referencing a single cell (e.g. "Mean for Semantic/Related/Vocal"):

```
standard.deviations <- matrix(
  nrow=matrix.rows, ncol=matrix.cols, byrow=TRUE,
  c(
    267, 174,
    263, 150,
    268, 171,
    235, 133
  ))
```

Does somebody know a Best Practice or common approach for storing data like this?

Comment: A data.frame seems like an appropriate structure to store this data of yours. You won't be able to have double column names (like vocal and gaze over the actual column names) but you could have Vocal_M, Vocal_SD .... Gaze_M, Gaze_SD columns in order to tell the difference.

Comment: This is probably offtopic here - It's not about programming per se. You could take a look at [this article](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) and [this previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83614/best-practices-for-creating-tidy-data)